# FTP connection (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, security

when I connected to a FTP-Server with sockets how can I send username and password?

thank you for your answers.

Comment: Who marked this down without leaving a comment why? Did they not feel this is a fair question?

Comment: You should read the FTP protocol documentation.

Answer (score 1):

FTP sends username and password in plain text, so you should be able to just invoke the commands and send them that way (at your own risk).

---

#### See also

- [List of FTP commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands)

  - `USER` - Authentication username.
  - `PASS` - Authentication password.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Jakarta Commons Net to handle this?

http://commons.apache.org/net/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)'s [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-net).